# Get param from html to java function call

Tags: java, html, servlets, parameters

I am working with a java generated dynamic webpage, and I'm printing links from a query to a JDO. But I don't understand how can I get and use the parameter from the url.

My html objects are printed like this

```
 print = print + "Nome:<a href='displayFotos?album="+results.get(i).nome+ "'>"+ 
 results.get(i).nome+ "</a></br>";
```

The results in having for example:

```
Nome:<a href='displayFotos?album=album1'>album1</a>
```

So, in my head when clicked it should be calling the address of the dynamic webpage album like this and should get the parameter. In this case it would be the album1.

```
  else if (address.indexOf("/dinamicas/album") != -1)   {
        String album = param1;
        System.out.println("did it work? "+album);
    }
```

And I have in the beginning of the class a general parameter that I use to get text from html forms.

```
  String param1 = req.getParameter("param1");
```

I understand this might be an easy question but I'm not getting there by myself.

Comment: querystrings (the part of the URI after the '?') get also written to the request object so you should be able to do `req.getParam("album")` and there's also `request.getQueryString()`

Comment: I'm not sure I am understanding the question... If you are asking how to get params from a request, then smeg4brains already addressed that (reques.getParameter("album")...

Comment: nice, both ways worked. If you answer it I will accept it immediately. Thank you

Comment: On a side note, you might consider using a StringBuilder instead of just string concatenation, plus, URL-Encoding, just in case the name of the album contains spaces, url-non-friendly characaters (&, ?) and so on...

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't getting the parameters of the request and what I was finding in web was using enumerations and some weird things that weren't working. But with the answer from semg4brains it works fine.

Comment: Hum, string builder? 

About the the url-encoding I didn't thought about it until you talked. But in a second though, I will just use the value of the google app engine generated key field from the JDO Identity NomeAlbums.class, that will solve the problem and will create no conflict when different albums have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  Nome:<a href='displayFotos?album=album1'>album1</a>
> ```

Here, you're using a parameter name of `album`.

However, you're attempting to get it by a parameter name of `param1`. This does obviously not match.

> ```
>  String param1 = req.getParameter("param1");
> ```

You need to use the same parameter name as is been definied in the request.

```
String album = req.getParameter("album");
// ...
```